# Quantization threshold selection

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I have the $256$-bin histogram representing a distribution of the values taken by a certain descriptor element. This descriptor element takes the values in $0-255$ range, hence $256$ bins. I want to compress this descriptor by limiting the resolution of the values that it can take. In order to do that, I would like to select $3$ thresholds for the aforementioned histogram which would divide the histogram into $4$ parts. Ideally, I would like to be able to do that automatically, since the shape of the distribution will change depending on the type of data used. I was thinking about a way of measuring how good the selected thresholds are and I came up with following idea:

1. I would normalise the values in each of the $4$ histogram parts independently and calculate the entropy. This would basically describe the randomness of the values in this part.
2. I would sum all $4$ entropy values, assuming that the best set of thresholds is the one, for which this sum takes the lowest value.

I think such an approach has a chance to succeed, but unfortunately I don't know about a numerical method which would allow me to come up with the solution.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Also, if you think that there is a better method of assessing a quality of selected threshold, please share your thoughts.

Comment: What about computing the quartile vaules of the histogram and use them as the descriptor ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is what did initially. I am trying to find more effective method. With quartiles, the problem was that sometimes the threshold would be selected right at the peak of the histogram, which is undesirable.

Comment: Why is that undesirable ? What matters usually, is that descriptors of similar features be similar.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, let's say the threshold is placed at the 100th bin, where also the histogram peak is. It means that the feature very often takes values in the range, let's say 90-110. If I quantize the values with the threshold at 100, values 99 and 101 (which are very similar and taken by the feature very often) will be classified as 'not-the-same'. Because they are so close, I would rather want them to be classified into the same group, which I believe will yield better results.

Comment: The idea is to compare the quartiles by Euclidean distance (1D).

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, maybe I simply misunderstood your idea. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: The quartiles are three numbers. They characterize the histogram in a compact and robust way.

Comment: Ok, I think I know where the misunderstanding is. The descriptor is not the histogram. The descriptor consists of 128 elements. Each of this elements can take a value between 0-255. I extract a number of descriptors from a data set and then analyze them all, by calculating histograms of 0-255 values occurrences for each of 128 elements. The thing is, I want to compress the descriptor by limiting the resolution a single element can take to 0-3 range. For that reason I want to split the histogram into 4 parts. I did it initially with quartiles and observed the problem described above.